# Is a geometric model applicable in this case?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Say we have a football player, and the probability he scores a penalty is $p$. I want to find:

1. Probability of player scoring more than $k$ penalties before missing a penalty.
2. Mean number of penalties scored before missing a penalty.

My attempt at 1. is the following

- Define 'success' as missing a penalty. Thus $P(\text{success})=1-p$
- Let $X$ be the number of trials up to and including the first success (that is, missing a penalty.)
- Since the geometric distribution is a model for the number of trials up to and including the first success, could we use $X \sim G(1-p)$ and then find $P(X > k) = 1 - F(k)$, the cdf of $X$?

And continuing from that, for 2. could we use the expected value of the geometric distribution defined in 1. ?

---

I need to admit I am quite confused by the wording of the questions, so I might be totally off by using a Geometric distribution.